# Pandas: adding one space around value in string column

Tags: python, pandas

I swear this should be easy, but I can't find the answer.

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', '3-3/4'], 
                   ['2', '1-1/2'],
                   ['3', '2'],
                   ['4', '5-1/4'],
                   ['5', '6']],
                  columns = ["ID", "Size"])
```

[image: Example dataframe]

All I want to do is to add one space before and after the value in the Size column. I've tried ljust, rjust, center, and pad, but they all fail to add because you have to account for the length of the string, which varies.

I want it to look something like this (pretend the x is a space):

[image: Needed outcome]

I've dug around online, but cannot find a way to resolve this. Would someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: you have 2 x's in the second row at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you just need

```
df['Size'] = ' ' + df['Size'] + ' '
```

Comment: OMG, thank you! I knew I was overthinking this, but could not see what I was missing.

Comment: @Heather happens to everyone :)